# Emulator restarts automatically each time while running program in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 3.0.1. I have used the emulator before in the same android studio and its perfect, but now emulator restarts itself during run. I had reset the adb, applied instant run, deleted all the emulators & also reinstalled the emulator from sdk manager but no use. 
Emulator restarts only when the app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, fix that worked for me:

Step 1:

```
 Open Avd Manager
  (or by pressing the Adv Manager icon in Android Studio Toolbar, or 
 on Windows -> control + shift + a  and in search box enter Adv Manager)*
```

Step 2:

```
if your emulator is running stop it.
found your emulator in the Avd Manager, in the end of the list(right side)
there is a drop down arrow, press it and  select "wipe data"
```

Step 3:

```
 start emulator from the Adv Manager, by pressing the play button (right side of drop down arrow in step 2 ). 

Wait till the emulator launches. When the emulator is up you can build your app.
```

Comment: Tried this but issue occurs again after some time.

Comment: Please elaborate why you down-voted my answer @ShangeethSivan

Comment: I tried the above steps but the issue occurs on every emulator im using. Even I tried creating a new one. Android Studio Version : 3.5 Android Emulator Version : 29.2.1

Comment: @ShangeethSivan Well you could just comment instead down voting my answer. For me and for few colleagues that worked. So it not a valid reason for your down vote.

Comment: ok Tried doing that seems I cannot upvote unless there is a change in the answer. Got this `You last voted on this answer Oct 16 at 10:06. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`